# How to smartly cache/expire asset files in development mode with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline, scalability

After building a heavy javascript application (SPA) on top of rails, right now, we are getting some trouble with scalability in development mode as our app grows. There are over 650 javascript files at moment and everytime we need to reload the page it takes about 30 seconds to complete and download all of them.

[image]

I was wondering if rails have any configuration options to cache those assets (not compress) in development mode and when any of them gets changed it expire the asset cache. Here is the development.rb file configuration:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Probably that option exists, just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Discourse has a large open source JavaScript based app (around 600 .js files) in Rails, https://github.com/discourse/discourse, maybe you can take a look there to see how they are handling it. Another options is to set `config.assets.debug` to `false`, that will not compress the files, just concatenate.

Comment: Sorry for double posting here, but this blog post may be relevant as well http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/05/03/eliminating-my-trivial-inconveniences, look under "I spend time making the development environment fast"

Comment: @kroofy thanks man, when I change the assets.debug to true my app just loaded so fast that I don't even tried the discourse turbo_dev.rb middleware solution, but I'll check it out.. btw, I can give you the reputation if you answer the question ;)

Comment: Are you sure its the file download time and not some JS that is blocking. Also are you sure its not the JS compile time thats slowing you down? You may want to look into lazy evaluation or async loading dependencies.

Comment: what was slowing down was certainly the number of requests and not the file size actually.. concatenating those files in one as @kroofy said solved the problem.. it went from 30 seconds (650 small files) to 4 seconds (1 big file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already posted as a comment, but he liked the answer so here it comes again.

The simplest option is to set `config.assets.debug` to `false`, that will not compress the files, just concatenate.

As a side-note, Discourse has a large open source JavaScript based app (around 600 .js files currently) in Rails, https://github.com/discourse/discourse, maybe you can take a look there to see how they are handling it. Here's a blog post detailing some possible work arounds in Discourse, http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/05/03/eliminating-my-trivial-inconveniences, look under "I spend time making the development environment fast".